winehq-stable is not installing
i was trying
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -o /etc/apt/keyrings/winehqarchive.key https://dl.winehq.org/winebuilds/winehq.key
sudo wget -NP  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/focal/winehq-focal.sources
sudo apt update

and then it shows these problem
w: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F

how to solve this ?
